# fully operational PLC with old pc using parallel port for inputs and outputs

Tags: plc

hey there I am looking all over the internet for something like an OS (operating System) or either a software that can be programmed as we program a PLC. and for inputs and outputs we use parallel port using flipflops we read and write the inputs and outputs either 16bit or 8bit.

Comment: Your question is not clear and lacks proper capitalisation and punctuation. Product recommendations are off-topic. Voting to close. Make a major edit if you wish to keep it open.

Comment: Codesys, however you'll find it hard to work with for PC, and it isn't really an "OS".

Comment: Have you seen the [OpenPLC Project](https://www.openplcproject.com/)?

Comment: @BenMiller-ReinstateMonica That's former Beremiz, isn't it?

Comment: @Transistor be patient. not everyone in this world is natively English speaking. and I thought that was the way to be specific and to the point. someone with common sense and knowledge about my question will understand perfectly what i'm talking about. sorry i had to be rude....

Comment: @BenMiller-ReinstateMonica yes I tried openPLC project but I think you still need the separate processor to run your program like rasberyPI or Arduino etc, Although I've been looking at this article and I cannot figure out the way to work it. [17 Channel Logic Analyzer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75279/17-Channel-Logic-Analyzer)

Comment: @Ahmad: That's fine, but you should state your location and maybe your language in your user profile so we can help you with translation and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You need an extension to the OS, c: alled real time kernel. In windows world it's called intervalzero, Linux has many others: RT-Linux, RTAI, preeemption POSIX,...Then you need a software or C code running in the real time kernel. This is Codesys, but also some free source like Matplc (however I don't know if still alive), ClassicLadder,..